# Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces and let $f$ be a continuous function from $X$ to $Y$. Then $f^{-1}$ is open for every open subset $U$ of $Y$.

Tags: real-analysis

There is a very clear proof in my book for this theorem. But I am trying to prove it using contradiction. To do such, I suppose that $v \subseteq Y$ is open in $Y$ and $f^{-1}(v) \subseteq X$ is open in $X$ But $f$ is not continuous in an arbitrary point like $p$:

$\exists \epsilon >0, \forall \delta>0, \exists x\in X, d(x,p)<\delta ,d(f(x),f(p))\geq \epsilon $
  (Is this hypothesis right?)

And I defined $S = \{x\in X \mid d(x,p)<\delta \land d(f(x),f(p))\geq \epsilon \}$

Now I want to show that if $S$ is non-empty then $f^{-1}$ of every open interval cant be an open interval. But I'm stuck here.

Comment: This is the definition of continuity of maps between topological spaces. And a metric space is a topological space :)

Comment: I think you are not assuming the right thing for a contradiction.  Original claim: For all continuous $f$, for all open sets $U$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.  The negation of this is: There exists some continuous $f$ for which there is some open set $U$ where $f^{-1}(U)$ is not open in $X$.  You do not want to assume that $f$ is not continuous.

Comment: Your assumption would be to show the converse, that if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for all open $U$, then $f$ is continuous.